# AttributeError for recursive method in python

Tags: python, exception, methods, recursion, attributeerror

I have a recursive method problem with python, the code is this:

```
class NodeTree(object):
    def __init__(self, name, children):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children

    def count(self):
        # 1 + i children's nodes
        count = 1
        for c in self.children:
            count += c.count()
        return count


def create_tree(d):
    N = NodeTree(d['name'], d['children'])
    print N.count()

d1 = {'name':'musica', 'children':[{'name':'rock', 'children':[{'name':'origini','children':[]},
                                                               {'name':'rock&roll','children':[]},
                                                               {'name':'hard rock', 'children':[]}]},
                                   {'name':'jazz', 'children':[{'name':'origini', 'children':[{'name':'1900', 'children':[]}]},
                                                               {'name':'ragtime', 'children':[]}, {'name':'swing', 'children':[]}]}]}
tree = create_tree(d1)
```

The error is this:

```
count += c.count()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'count'
```

I tried anything but it doesn't work.

Anyway, any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because Python dictionaries do not have a `count` method.

It'll help if we go over line by line what your code is actually doing.

```py
    def count(self):
        # 1 + i children's nodes
        count = 1
        for c in self.children:      ## self.children is a list of dictionaries, so each c is a dictionary
            count += c.count()       ## We are getting .count() of c--which is a dictionary
        return count
```

This is because we passed d1['children'] as self.children, which is a list of dictionaries: `[<dict>, <dict>, <dict>, ... ]`.

Rather than `count()`, what you should do is call `len` on the dictionary, to get the number of keys it has, thus becoming:

```py
    for c in self.children:
        count += len(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

`d['children']` is a `list of dict`, as you can see in `d1` dict.

Now, when you iterate over your `children`, in `NodeTree`, which is essentially `d['children']` only, you will get `dictionary` as each element: -

```
for c in self.children:  // c is a `dict` type here
    count += c.count()   // there is not attribute as `count` for a `dict`.
```

And hence you got that error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for once, the `create_tree` function does not build the tree recursively. So you just add a Node on zero level and the the children are just dictionaries.

The following (modified) code (although quickly typed and sloppy) should do a recursive
build of the tree. Didn't check your `count` code, but assuming it is correct, it should work.

```
class NodeTree(object):
    def __init__(self, name, children):
        self.name = name
        self.children = children

    def count(self):
        # 1 + i children's nodes
        count = 1
        for c in self.children:
            count += c.count()
        return count


def deep_create_tree(d):
    if len(d["children"]) > 0:
        chlds = []
        for i in d["children"]:
            chlds.append(deep_create_tree(i))
    else:
        chlds = []
    n = NodeTree(d["name"], chlds)
    return n


d1 = {'name':'musica', 'children':[{'name':'rock', 'children':[{'name':'origini','children':[]},{'name':'rock&roll','children':[]},{'name':'hard rock', 'children':[]}]},{'name':'jazz', 'children':[{'name':'origini', 'children':[{'name':'1900', 'children':[]}]},{'name':'ragtime', 'children':[]}, {'name':'swing', 'children':[]}]}]}

def scan_tree(tr):
    print tr.name, tr.count()
    for i in tr.children:
        scan_tree(i)

tr = deep_create_tree(d1)
scan_tree(tr)
```

Comment: @LorenzoViola Fixed some identation errors, you may want to retry it. What are you expecting as an output? The above code (actually, the scan_tree part) outputs the following: 'musica 10
rock 4
origini 1
rock&roll 1
hard rock 1
jazz 5
origini 2
1900 1
ragtime 1
swing 1'. In any case, you should probably replace your `create_tree` because it doesn't do a recursive creation

Answer (score 0):

The best (and the only desirable) way is to have a recursive creation of your node tree. This can be done in two different ways, either make your `NodeTree.__init__()` recursively init all of the children (which again recursively init all of their children, etc) or you can make your `create_tree()` function recursive.

I'd personally use recursive `__init__()`, but it's your call.

---

Recursive `__init__()` for creating tree structure:

```
def __init__(self, name, children=[]):
    self.name = name
    self.children = []
    for c in children:
        self.children.append(
            self.__class__(c['name'], c['children']))
```

This way `self.children` will contain other `NodeTree`s instead of `dict`s. Also you no longer need to declare empty children list, instead of:

```
d2 = {'name':'sterile', 'children':[]}
```

do

```
d2 = {'name':'sterile'}
```

And the initializer will automatically set children to `[]`

---

If you want to use a recursive `create_tree()` function, it's also possible, and not a bad idea either. However you will still have to edit the `__init__()` -method, it no longer takes children as parameter. Or as I did here, it does, but you hardly ever use it.

```
# NodeTree
def __init__(self, name, children=None):
    self.name = name
    if children:
        self.children = children

def create_tree(d):
    N = NodeTree(d['name'])
    for c in d['children']:
        N.children.append(create_tree(c))
    return N
```

This will have basically the same results.